# ScriptError: Exception: Object is not of type Shape

Tags: google-apps-script

ScriptError: Exception: Object is not of type Shape

code presently:

```
    var slideee = slides[0];
    var elems = slideee.getPageElements();
    var txt=""; 
    elems.forEach(
      ((el,index)=>{
        txt = txt + el.asShape().getText().asString().replace("\n", "");
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

only make a change at one line which is using .asShape() function:

```
if(el.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE")
txt = txt + el.asShape().getText().asString().replace("\n", "");
```

and it worked by using it.